# MongoDB/Mongoose aggregate, stage result undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get comments from a MongoDB collection (using Mongoose) and calculate the number of comments and the average using the aggregate pipeline. However, when the first $match returns nothing the script crashes with a 'Cannot read property 'avg' of undefined' error.

```
    var q = Comment.aggregate([
    { $match: {
        _post: this,
        rating: { $gt: 0 },
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: null,
        avg: { $avg: "$rating" },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }}
]);

q.exec(function(err, result) {
    cb(err, result[0].avg, result[0].count);
});
```

When I leave out the _post $match the result contains the correct average and count of all comments, but when $match does not return anything, it simply throws an error.. How to fix?

Comment: why do you need `_post: this`? Aggregation pipeline works sequentially. `$group` will work with a cursor after previous query (if exists).

Comment: The code snippet is part of a instance method of a Post Mongoose object. The _post: this refers to the object itself, to get only comments belonging to that particular post. $group indeed works after an empty result from the previous stage, but I was just looking at the wrong place (see answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the wrong place. The error message did not refer to the 'avg' in the query, but to the result.avg in the callback function. Just before posting I had changed the callback function parameters to result[0].avg, and now the error message was about not able to read '0' from undefined.

Staring myself blind at the wrong place.. Posted just too soon..